# using boto3 to get usage data of a user based on tag value

Tags: amazon-web-services, boto3, aws-cost-explorer

Im trying to use boto3 w cost explorer to get usage data of user based on tag value. but It keeps timing out. Is this below script correct? There are no errors but I see no output

```
import boto3

ce_client = boto3.client('ce')

# Granularity='DAILY'|'MONTHLY'|'HOURLY'

time_period = {
    'Start': '2023-05-05',
    'End': '2023-06-06'
}

# Specify the filter for the tag key ('User') and tag value ('sample')
tag_filter = {
    'Tags': {
            'Key': 'User',
            'Values': [
                'sample',
            ]
            }
            }

# Retrieve cost and usage data based on the specified tag filter
response = ce_client.get_cost_and_usage(
    TimePeriod=time_period,
    Granularity='MONTHLY',
    Metrics=['BlendedCost'],
    Filter=tag_filter
)

# Process the response data as needed
print(response)  # Example: Print the response (adjust as per your requirement)


#print("EC2 Instance IDs:", instance_ids)
```

altrernatively ive tried to use AWS CLI to do this but it keeps stalling and timing out. this is what i used

```
aws ce get-cost-and-usage \
    --time-period Start=2023-05-01,End=2023-06-01 \
    --granularity MONTHLY \
    --metrics "BlendedCost" \
    --filter "Tags.Key=User,Values=sample"
```

thanks in advance!

Comment: `--filter "Tags.Key=User,Values=sample"` this does not look right to me based on [the documentation](https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/ce/get-cost-and-usage.html)

Comment: {"Tags": { "Key": "TagName", "Values": ["Value1"] } } ]}, I've done this too but nothing seems to work. @erik258.  for the code too i just followed their documentation but i see no input and it keeps timing out(I have admin access to the data so idk why).

Comment: Does it timeout if you do _NOT_ specify a filter?

Comment: It's interesting behavior.  I'm trying to reproduce and I can't get a timeout even on a pretty large account.

Comment: You are saying you tried `--filter{"Tags":{"Key":"User","Values": ["sample"]}}]}`?

Comment: @erik258 Are you using cli or something similar to the above script I used. Could this be a permissions issue of some sort. I using jupyter notebook, could this be affecting it?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein I did try that but same issue.

Comment: I'm using the CLI based on what you did.  There must be something making this network request especially  / interminably slow for you.  " I using jupyter notebook, could this be affecting it?"  wouldn't hurt to take that out of the equation.

Comment: so the cli worked for ya? interesting. what environment are you doing this, local temrinal, virtual machine, local vs code teminal, ? ill try to do what you did. Im tryna see if theres some permissions issue @erik258

Comment: local terminal on a mac.  Pretty much the same command you did - with AWS CLI V2 which you should absolutely be using for everything.  On an account that handles billing for 70+ AWS accounts and quite a bit of AWS spend.